# How to merge Array value with key name in mongo db

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query

```
{
    _id :{
        "foo" : "abc"
    },
    "time" :[],
    "bar": [
        [],
        []
    ]
}
```

Expected Output `abc` become the key `bar`

```
{
    "_id" :{
        "foo" : abc
    },
    "time" :[],
    "abc": [
        [],
        []
    ]
}
```

Comment: Check [$rename](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/rename/) operator.

Comment: it's not working in my case, I have multiple documents, or can you describe me in detail or post some query, that would be helpful

Comment: Can you provide a better example and explanation?. With this data I'm assuming you only want to rename ```bar``` to ```abc```. But, is ```abc``` given or is neccesary get from the ```_id.foo``` field?

Comment: yes, it is compulsory to get from `_id.foo`.
so, `abc` is dynamically changing, but `bar` is the key name, it contains the values of `abc`
Expeceted result is `abc` as the name of array and get values.

Comment: do you want to update `update()` this documents? or just want to get and display `aggregate()` ?

Comment: I want to get and Display the `aggregate()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try,

- `$arrayToObjects` to set `foo` as k(key) and `bar` as v(value) and convert to object format
- `$mergeObjects` to merge `$$ROOT` and above operation result
- `$replaceRoot` to replace above both merge object result in root
- `$project` to remove `bar` field because we don't needed

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: {
        $mergeObjects: [
          { $arrayToObject: [[{ k: "$_id.foo", v: "$bar" }]] },
          "$$ROOT"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  { $project: { bar: 0 } }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Ze61sux4JeE)

Comment: your sol is work if I have documents as an array but I don't have the document as array. I have structure like this
`{`
    _id :{
        "foo" : "abc"
    },
    "time" :[],
    "bar": [
        [],
        []
    ]
`}`
your sol is work IF
 `[`
    _id :{
        "foo" : "abc"
    },
    "time" :[],
    "bar": [
        [],
        []
    ]
`]`

Comment: Yes its an array its just structure of playground website, you can run this query in your platform this will work.

Comment: When I run it , I get error message : '$arrayToObject requires an object keys of 'k' and 'v'. Found incorrect number of keys:1' on server .

Comment: have you executed same query?

Comment: yes,  I executed, the same query as you give. but as I said I have one document with `{ }` your query is working with `[ ]`.

Comment: That is not problem, its playground structure this will work in your platform, what is the version of mongodb?

Comment: 4.2 version I'm using

Comment: Can you try this query [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/GhbXeSyZfZc)

Comment: Thanks!, I try it, but did not get my solution :( In [https://mongoplayground.net/p/GhbXeSyZfZc] its working fine

Comment: what are you getting in this query? and where you executing this query?

Comment: I'm getting per record `abc` as a document, and run the query in the Organization platform